# Application Usage Statistics

Tags: applications

Is there any way to get application usage statistics?

Specifically, I would like to know how many times an application (like for example Hangouts, or Firefox) is started. And by that, I mean times that the application was active/full screen, not just in the memory.

Comment: Many apps are available just search for "track usage" on Play Store

Comment: Since Android 5 there is the `UsageStatsManager` which collects data about how long an app is/was in foreground. Therefore this data should be easily to get by common apps.